# Fetch Jfrog artifact through API in Jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, artifactory

I need to use it in Jenkins pipeline without using the plugin.

**Is there a way to fetch artifact from JFrog using API?**

I have a Jenkins job where I have to draft a shell script which fetches the artifact from jfrog. If it was in Jenkins-file I would have used the plug-in. Is there a API way of doing it so that I can put that API in my shell script and run it from Jenkins pipeline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the AQL(Artifactory Query Language) to get the artifacts through api. Like this

```
curl -u<user>:<password> -X POST -k -H 'Content-Type:text/plain' -i https://<artifactory_host>/artifactory/api/search/aql
```

If you want to filter the result then you can add condtions to api by passing json

```
curl -u<user>:<password> -X POST -k -H 'Content-Type:text/plain' -i https://<artifactory_host>/artifactory/api/search/aql  --data 'items.find({"name" : {"$match":"*.jar"}}).include("name")'
```